# Creating a new authentication service through a Salesforce app

Tags: visualforce, force.com, appexchange

I'll start this by saying that I've never used Salesforce.

I've been given the task to investigate if it's feasible for the company I work for to create a Salesforce app that provides an authentication feature through our services, similar to oAuth. I'm going through the documentation, but it's hard for me to understand if there's a need for something like this.

If yes, can anybody point me in the right direction on how to approach the development? Thanks.

Comment: You can start from here - [Configure a Salesforce Authentication Provider](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sso_provider_sfdc.htm)

Comment: @Oleksiy Will this allow me to have a custom login process? It't not going to be the classic enter username and password flow.